# Edge Detection and explicit Identification

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I want to know how to update the canny Edge Image with the detected and sorted Hough lines. I think this is a basic question but this is the first time I am trying this. I have checked on OpenCv org, but it has the new C++ API. Can someone help me as I am using the C API.

Comment: [`cvCanny`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#canny) here you find  `cpp`, `c`,`python` api reference. check through

Comment: the c-api is deprecated, and you should not use it

Answer (score 0):

I have finally decided to update to C++ API and yes, will try to rewrite anything existing in deprecated API into new. Thanks berak for being consistent on your suggestion. Kudos!!!

Update: I have also figured out the solution in the C API.

```
CvMemStorage *LineStack = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* Lines = cvHoughLines2(pImage, LineStack, CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC, 1, CV_PI/180, 10, 10, 0.2);
```

Note: pImage is the canny derivate